# IIS Cross-Domain Redirection POST?

Tags: asp.net, iis, cross-domain, http-post, redirect

Is it possible to have an ASP.NET web proxy accept a GET request from the client, perform a POST to an external website, and then send the external POST response back to the original client in the form of a redirect (URL change in address bar)?

The client calls my proxy like this: `internalWebsite.com?userId=1234`.

Server-side, I then create an HttpWebRequest (POST) pointed to the external URL, take that `userId` query string to build a token and place it in the HttpWebRequest Authorization header, which the external site requires for authentication.

When this response comes back, I return the external HTML response string to the original client. The problem is that the HTML page has relative links to images, css, pages that do not work since the browser still thinks it is on my internal website.

I have seen many examples of doing external GET, and even external POST as long as I don't need the authorization header, but I cannot get this to work. See code below...

```
string url = "externalWebSite.com/login";

StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append("post data goes here");

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;

myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + token);
request.Headers = myWebHeaderCollection;

request.AllowAutoRedirect = true; //new
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postData.ToString().Length;                        
//request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
request.UserAgent = ".NET Web Proxy";
request.Referer = url;

StreamWriter writer = null;

try
{
    writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(postData.ToString());
    writer.Flush();

    HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    //Now, we read the response (the string), and output it.   
    Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);

    _context.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    _context.Response.ContentType = WebResp.ContentType;
    _context.Response.Write(_Answer.ReadToEnd());
}
finally
{
    if (writer != null)
        writer.Close();
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you recieve content, try to insert html-tag "base" just after "head" section begins:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <base href="http://externalWebSite.com">
   ... <!-- content from externalWebSite.com -->
```

Also, if you want to display all content that you recieved, it is better override Render method on your page:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    string result = GetContentFromTherOtherSite();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    base.Render(htw);
    writer.Write(result);
}
```

In this case, on your page there will be only content from the other site, without your tags.

Comment: This did the trick! Now it is not holding on to the authentication once I click a page link. I'm hoping I can simply copy some headers/cookies.

Comment: You cannot access cookies for security reasons - cookie from domain1.com can be accessed only from this domain and its subdomains. Also, auth inforation might be stored in session of the other site - you cannot assess it, too. Will be the better decision to use IFRAME to display the other site on your page?

Comment: I would prefer to have the entire page be routed to external website. That being said, I also would like this to work. Even with an IFRAME, I need to send that Authorization header through the POST, so do you think that is possible?